# Mi adaptador personalizado no actualiza con el método notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, customadapter

Hace tiempo que uso Filterable y todo iba correcto pero desde la ultima versión de Android Studio no me funciona correctamente debido a que no se activa el método notifyDataSetChanged().

Aquí dejo el código de mi Adaptador que desciende de RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
 @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String key = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();

                if(key.isEmpty()){
                    listFiltrada = list;
                }else {
                    // Primer filtro
                    List<PostBlog> filtro = new ArrayList<>();
                    // Realizamos la buscqueda en el post
                    for (PostBlog post : list){
                        if (post.getTitulo().toLowerCase().contains(key)){
                            filtro.add(post);
                        }
                    }
                    listFiltrada = filtro;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = listFiltrada;

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                listFiltrada = (List<PostBlog>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

Hasta donde he podido comprobar la lista filtrada llega correcta hasta publishResults() pero no actualiza mi RecyclerView

Answer (score 3):

Si `getFilter()` se encuentra dentro de tu Adapter, realiza lo siguiente usando también `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` :

```
@Override
  protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
    listFiltrada = (List<PostBlog>) filterResults.values;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    clear();

    int count = listFiltrada.size();
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
        add(listFiltrada.get(i));
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Jorge. Esos métodos no son de getFiltrer(), ¿de donde los sacas?

Comment: El método notifyDataSetChanged() es del adapter. y  Notifica a los observadores adjuntos que los datos subyacentes se han cambiado y que cualquier Vista que refleje el conjunto de datos debe actualizarse.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, el problema es que el edittext estaba fuera del fragmento y por lo cual no actualizaba.